# Transform to XML: Send ID to XSL Param

Tags: php, xml, xslt

I'm not sure how to word this or if the title of my problem makes sense.

In my index.php page, I am querying data from the database. The data I am fetching is title, job_id, and location.

I would like to turn the job_id into a href link, that when clicked on will send the job id that is clicked on to job_postings.xsl

```
<td><div align="center"><?=$row["job_id"];?></div></td>
```

Here is the code from job_postings.xsl:

```
<xsl:param name="job_id">90186036</xsl:param>
    <xsl:template match="/">
```

I need to be able to send the current job id of whatever link it clicked to job_postings.xsl to replace 90186036

Any help what be greatly appreciated. I have tried much troubleshooting with no luck.

Comment: XSLT/XSL is a script file used to style/transform XML, not intended to be interacted by a user. What does job_postings.xsl intended to do? Please describe your final desired result such as web page or xml output.

Comment: Maybe this link will help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375278/passing-parameters-in-xml

Comment: @Parfait - I need to be able to grab the id of the link that is selected and send that id to the job_postings.xsl to replace the current param id number. The job_postings.xsl page needs to display the information for whatever link id is selected. If I click on a link with a job id of 90123468, the page needs to display the information associated with that id. If I click on a different id, it needs to display only the information for that id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my job_overview.php page, I had to add the following code to grab the id of the job that was selected when the user clicks on submit on the index.php page.

```
$proc->setParameter('', 'job_id', $_POST["id"]);
```

I also decided to use a form to make the process much easier.

```
<form method='POST' action='job_overview.php'><b>SELECT A JOB TO VIEW:</b><br />
```